# Unable to run ssh inside shell script

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I am able to run `ssh rach@kamel` but if i try to put this in `bash script`, i get command not found.

Here is the bash script in question

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh rach@kamel
```

i also tried using kamel ip address instead, still same issue.

***Update*** Here is the *Exact* message

```
$ ./devBuild.sh
: No such file or directory../
: command not found
```

***Update*** Content of `cat -A devBuild.sh`

```
$ cat -A devBuild.sh
#!/bin/bash^M$
cd ../^M$
ssh adoshi@10.247.39.142 ^M$
```

***Update*** : Now am getting

`$ ./devBuild.sh
: hostname nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: How do you run your script? Looks like the script does not have the same `$PATH` as your interactive shell.

Comment: Strange. Try replacing `ssh` with full path, i.e. the output of `type ssh` (usually `/usr/bin/ssh`).

Comment: @choroba: did that but still am getting same command not found...

Comment: Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: @choroba: updated question with the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

^M$ is symptom of DOS line-end, fix that and you should be good.

Comment: it should fix the issue but now I get hostname or service not found but again I can directly do ssh from prompt and it works fine....

Comment: that means there are something tagged to the end on your ssh line and it was being read as part of the host-name, you should look carefully. Or if you don't know what is there, put a semi-colon after it like ssh user@hostname;

Answer (score 3):

Do you, by any chance, have the line endings wrong? Sometimes it happens that there is a `\r\n` at the end of lines instead of a mere `\n`. This makes the shebang (`#!`) line dysfunctional.

Could you post the result of `cat -A dev.sh`, especially the first line?

Comment: update question with the content..., i should have mentioned that am modifying script on windows OS and running in via cygwin...

Answer (score 0):

Is your script executable? If not use chmod +x dev.sh